# git : list names of people who did not work in period of time

Tags: git, github

Im new user to git.
Im using git on my terminal.
I have to check a project and see who are the contributors that have been inactive for the past six month or more than six month.
I tried to many commands and I could not find the answer.
so basically I need to print names of people who did not contributes in the project for more than 6 month 
Thanks

Comment: Are you sure that your question is about **git** and not **GitHub**?

Comment: yes, Im analyzing a repository and learn to extract data from there

Comment: Your question is unclear. You should clarify your goals, provide examples and explain what commands you have tried and what was wrong with them. I would assume you're talking about git commands (possibly in conjunction with a Unix shell).

Comment: I thought the question was pretty clear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taking the question as literally as possible, here's a BASH script to get the names of all authors who haven't committed in the past 6 months.

```
#!/bin/bash

since=$(date -d"-6 months" +%Y-%m-%d)

git shortlog -sn | awk '{$1=""; print $0}' > /tmp/herolist

while read author; do
    if [[ $(git log --after=$since --author="$author") == "" ]]; then
        echo $author
    fi
done < /tmp/herolist
```

---

Edited to show people who have**n't** committed in the past six months.

Comment: thank you for answer but it showing this error>> usage: date [-jnu] [-d dst] [-r seconds] [-t west] [-v[+|-]val[ymwdHMS]] ... [-f fmt date | [[[mm]dd]HH]MM[[cc]yy][.ss]] [+format] –

Comment: You're using MacOS? Try `date -v -6m +Y-%m-%d` on the third line instead

Answer (score 1):

You see if a contributor has any commits after a certain date (6 months in past):

`git log --after="yyyy-mm-dd" --author="email or name"`

If command result is empty, there are no commits

Comment: what if i did not want to write names because they are more than 50, what should I do in this case?

Comment: you could do a for loop on name list

Answer (score 1):

A more literal answer as the question was talking about committers and not authors. Also doesn't use a temporary file. But there is still room to improve.

```
#! /bin/bash

IFS=$'\n'
limit=$(date --date='-6 month' +"%d-%m-%Y")
committers=$(git log --pretty=format:"%cn" | sort -u | uniq -u)
recent_committers=$(git log --pretty=format:"%cn" --after $limit | sort -u | uniq -u)

for i in ${recent_committers[@]}; do
    committers=( "${committers[@]/$i}" )
done

printf -- "%s\n" "${committers[@]}"
```

Comment: thank you for answer but it showing this error>> date: illegal option -- -
usage: date [-jnu] [-d dst] [-r seconds] [-t west] [-v[+|-]val[ymwdHMS]] ... 
            [-f fmt date | [[[mm]dd]HH]MM[[cc]yy][.ss]] [+format]

Comment: I appreciate your effort but it did print all names even who committed this month

Answer (score 0):

You can get the timestamp and author of all commits using the pretty formatting options:

```
git log --pretty="%at:%an:%ae"
```

You can either use `%at` and get unixtime, then use that to sort and 'unique' the data - or you can use `%ai` or `%aD` if you want a human-readable date to look over.